# Unable to SSH to my virtual machine via Windows Power Shell ISE

Tags: ssh, powershell, vmware-workstation

Well, I have a Linux virtual machine running in my vmWare. And I would actually love to use my Linux in Windows Power Shell. So I usually use it by doing an SSH to my VM. Recently I came across the "Windows Power Shell ISE" where you can have the feature of opening multiple tabs and other cool stuff.

Here comes the actual problem, when I try to do SSH to my virtual machine, the SSH Operation is being stucked and it is not showing me any further console or message. I am having an SSH Client that comes with GIT, Windows 8.1 and vmWare Workstation 10.

```
PS C:\> ssh esis@192.168.255.142
ssh : Warning: Permanently added '192.168.255.142' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
At line:1 char:1
+ ssh esis@192.168.255.142
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Warning: Perman...of known hosts.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: This appears to be a problem with specific software, not server administration.  If thats the case you will probably get better feedback on another Stackexchange site - perhaps Stackoverflow or Superuser (Or just contact support).  Serverfault is intended to be a place for questions about 'professional systems and network admins'.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer to your question but an extended comment.**

It is probably related to host-key records in your ssh client.

Here is the possible longer version of the message that is abbreviated in your console output.

```
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.255.142' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
...
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

It is likely waiting for `yes/no` input from the console, while console input and output is redirected somewhere by powershell.

Try to disable host-key checking in your `ssh` configuration or clean-up the host keys.

Comment: I am unable to type anything after the error message which it is throwing. I need to  do **Ctrl+C** for stopping the operation. As per the error message, probably it is throwing some exception which I am unable to rectify. Any idea on RemoteException/NativeCommandError?

Comment: @SriHarshaKappala as I said, your console input might be redirected somewhere. Try `ssh` with the option `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`